# Is there a way to get a variable in rows and columns

Tags: python, for-loop

How to get output like this in python from for loop

Input = 2

Result =

```
     **
     **
```

Comment: You can just print your result with literals. Did you mean that the input may vary? What would be the result with other inputs? Can you give some examples?

Comment: This looks like homework... As a former teacher, it's quite important that you manage to achieve this by yourself. Otherwise, the next month will be hard in your CS classroom.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
Nested for

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print('*', end='')
    print('\n')
```

Option 2:
String multiplication

```
for i in range(2):
    print('*' * 2)
```